# namenode recovery hadoop 2.x(active and passive namenode)

Tags: hadoop2

in hadoop 2.X we are having the concept of active namenode and passive namenode and both used to write fsimage and editlogs to a shared location.

what happens when cluster looses the access to that shared location.
i mean is there a concept of taking backup of shared location also in hadoop 2.X

Please suggest.